# Allow to create new tags on mobile

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, tag-creation

Presently, users aren't allowed to create new tags from mobile. The restriction is in place perhaps to avoid errors/mistakes.

But, seriously I don't get it. Its the era of smartphones. Today, we do important business emails from mobile. And, if we can write full body of questions from mobile without error, why can't we create tags without error.

Look at my habits:
When I have tag creation privilege, I don't bother to delay the asking until I am on PC. I also don't bother to post question with incomplete set of tags or fake tags and flag the moderator. Its because I have quick way. I just change user agent to desktop and create desired tag. Tag creation on full site with small screen!!! See, how much error-prone it can be (any user can do this)? 
Well, I haven't done a mistake with this yet, but I face troubles with extra steps.

Another thing: Such things shouldn't be problem when everything on SE is editable.

Please, allow creating new tags on mobile devices.

**Update:**
Keep new tag warning on place like "These tags are new: xxx, yyy. Do you want to continue?" It can be useful when a user wants to use existing tag, but there's a typo.

Comment: The full site is also accessible from your mobile. That seems like a sufficient workaround for those rare instances where you just *need* to create a tag on-the-go.

Comment: @Cody Yes, it is. But, why a workaround and restriction on mobile theme when it's not necessary?

Comment: The whole point of mobile theme is to make everything on small screen easy.

Comment: Right. The point of the mobile theme is to offer the most important features in an easy-to-use format targeted to small screens. Adding a bunch of rarely used features runs counter to that goal.